# Please translate this Chinese calligraphy into English

Tags: calligraphy

This was on a large painting that someone bought many years ago, but I do not know what it says.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't read it all, his writing is somewhat, "artistic"! X means illegible (for me). Read from right to left, and top to bottom.

I'm sure others here can do much better! The artist's paintings are beautiful, they must be quite valuable!

傲雪迎春XX丁亥年(2007?)冬月(11th lunar month),
proud snow welcomes spring XX 2007? 11th lunar month

XX王成喜 (the artist),
Wang Cheng Xi (the artist born, 1940),

于北京龙潭之畔香雪斋让X梅姿 （梅花的姿态）
on the bank of Beijing Dragon Pool fragrant snow building?  Let X plum blossom pose?

Comment: Thank You for working on this piece...

Answer (score 1):

This is “inscriptions” in Chinese painting:

```
梅謹齋香之龍於王中冬年丁時迎傲
姿寫　雪畔潭北成州　之卯在春雪
　　　　　　京喜
```

Just like @Pedroski said, the "correct reading order" is:

```
傲雪迎春，時在丁卯年之冬。中州王成喜，於北京龍潭之畔香雪齋，謹寫梅姿。
```

In simplified-chinese:

```
傲雪迎春，时在丁卯年之冬。中州王成喜，于北京龙潭之畔香雪斋，谨写梅姿。
```

`傲雪迎春`: Major Snow(傲雪) is waiting for(迎,welcome) the spring(春).

`时在丁卯年之冬`: The time is(时在) winter of(之冬) 1987(丁卯, see [干支,Sexagenary cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle)).

`中州王成喜`： [Henan(中州)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henan)  [Wang-Chengxi（王成喜）](https://www.mutualart.com/Artist/Wang-Chengxi/CB23918D373B02A2)

`于北京龙潭之畔香雪斋`：In(于) the room fragrant-snow(香雪斋,elegant name of study room), which stands near(之畔) the Beijing Longtan-lake(北京龙潭(湖)).

`谨写梅姿`:  Drawing(写) the posture of plum blossom(梅姿) piously(谨).

By the way, fragrant-snow is the another name for plum blossom.